# Basic Ocaml: How do I compile this?

Tags: ocaml, opam

Just beginning with ocaml and am struggling with the various compilers and tooling. E.g. `ocamlopt`, `ocamlc`, `ocamlbuild`, `corebuild` and so on.  So, how do I compile the following?

```
open Core.Std

module Regex = Re2.Regex

let ls pattern = 
  let pat = Regex.create_exn pattern in
  let matcher = Regex.matches pat in
  Sys.ls_dir "." 
  |> List.filter ~f:matcher
  |> List.iter ~f:(fun s -> print_string s; print_newline ())

let () =
  match In_channel.input_line stdin with
  | None -> print_string "No Input"
  | Some pat -> ls pat
```

In `utop` I can just `#require "re2"` and go from there.

Without the inclusion of the regular expressions module I would just use `corebuild ls.native`, assuming that the above code is placed into `ls.ml`.

[edit]

Have so far tried

`ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -package core -package re2`

which spit out

```
ocamlfind ocamldep -package core -package re2 -modules ls.ml > ls.ml.depends
ocamlfind ocamlc -c -package core -package re2 -o ls.cmo ls.ml
+ ocamlfind ocamlc -c -package core -package re2 -o ls.cmo ls.ml
ocamlfind: Error from package `threads': Missing -thread or -vmthread switch
Command exited with code 2.
```

So after some googling I was led to [this blog](http://gallium.inria.fr/blog/quick-tip-the-ocamlbuild-documentation-option/) I tried

`ocamlbuild -tag thread -use-ocamlfind -package core -package re2`

which spits out over 6000 lines of what looks like `make` output before failing with:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
File "caml_startup", line 1:
Error: Error during linking
Command exited with code 2.
```

so I'm not sure what to try next.

Comment: Got it to compile quite nicely with `ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -package re2 -package core ls.byte` but run into troubles when compiling to native.

Comment: for the brave: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/971d9501385e144855d7 the first file is the output from ocamlbuild, the second is the file being compiled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on a 64bit machine.  I ditched the apt-get versions of ocaml:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ocaml ocaml-base-nox ocaml-compiler-libs \ 
                            ocaml-interp ocaml-native-compilers \ 
                            ocaml-nox campl4 ocaml-base ocaml-docs opam
```

Then I installed opam from source according to the instructions [here](http://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Advanced_Install.html).

Next I installed core, utop, and re2 with `opam install core utop re2`

And finally I ran `ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -package re2 -package core -tag thread ls.native`

which built the desired executable.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use oasis tool. It is not as hard, as one may think. But it removes all library burden from you.

Lets create a simple `_oasis` file for your project:

```
OASISFormat: 0.4
Name:        ls
Version:     0.1
Synopsis:    Testing oasis
Authors:     Fizz_ed
License:     MIT
Plugins:     META (0.4), DevFiles (0.4)
BuildTools: ocamlbuild, camlp4o
BuildDepends: core, camlp4, threads, 
              sexplib.syntax, 
              bin_prot.syntax, 
              comparelib.syntax, 
              herelib, 
              herelib.syntax

Executable "ls"
  Path: .
  MainIs: ls.ml
  CompiledObject: best
  BuildDepends: re2
```

After you've created this file, run `oasis setup` command (if `oasis` is not installed, then install it using opam, or your package manager).

After that you will have a common `configure` script and makefiles. So all you need is to type

```
./configure
make
```

and your file will be compiled.

Or you can just use `ocamlbuild` directly, it will work too, since oasis created all the necessary files

```
ocamlbuild ls.native
```

A few explanations about the file. The preamle contains everything you need to build your core-style applications.

Executable section describes your executable file, and also adds a dependency to re2 library.

Update: fixed some issues.

Comment: Calling `oasis setup` returns with `W: Unknown license 'BSD-3-clause' in 'BSD-3-clause'`

Comment: Ok, let's try something simplier. MIT for example. I've updated the post. Maybe your oasis is too old...

Comment: btw, it is a warning only, that what `W` stands for, so it should work

Comment: So yes, it was just a warning. did `./configure; make` but got the same error as above (after the 6k line output), followed by an additional error: `E: Failure("Command ''/home/thatsme/.opam/4.01.0/bin/ocamlbuild' ls.native -tag debug' terminated with error code 10")`

Comment: (and just to make sure we're sane here, it does run in utop)

Comment: (Also compiles just fine with ls.byte)

Comment: that is strange. First of all, try to start from scratch. Create a new folder, put in it two files: `_oasis` and `ls.ml`. Then type `oasis setup`. If it outputs nothing it is ok. Otherwise, post the output here. After that type `./configure`, it shouldn't emit `confiruration errors, or something like this. After that type `make`. If it still doesn't work, give me a link to the gist with output.

Comment: it compiles perfectly fine on my machine. Btw, what OS are using?

Comment: Tried out above in clean directory to the effect already reported. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.1 on a Thinkpad T430.

Comment: excellent environment. So, please upload a  gist with error. Apparently you have problems with installation.

Comment: hah, coincidentally I was doing just that. In the comments of my post.

Comment: And here's the oasis output  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a2a7d72092c1c1d846c9

Comment: Looks like, that re2 library can't find you C++ standard library. I can only suggest you to try to reinstall it with `opam reinstall re2`

Comment: and make sure, that you have installed `libstdc++` library.

Comment: Yeah. After looking for which version the re2 project (googlecode) uses, I've just finished installing 3 versions libstdc++, and the -dev variants.  Still no luck.

Comment: In any case, I think my question has been ruled out as having to do with OCaml. Thankfully, I could probably compile most any ocaml program I want now! So, thanks.