# How do I compile/build against Ocamlodbc

Tags: database, odbc, ocaml

I've installed Ocamlodbc using `opam install odbc`, but I can't work out how to build an app that uses it with ocamlbuild.  The examples that come with the source don't build either.

If I put

```
#require "odbc";;
```

into my `.ocamlinit`, I can `open Odbc_unixodbc;;` in **utop**, but any reference to functions in that module result in a "Reference to undefined global 'Odbc_unixodbc'" error.

The following snippet also fails with an error about no implementation for "Odbc_unixodbc"

```
open Odbc_unixodbc

let () =   ignore (Odbc_unixodbc.connect "DSN" "UID" "PWD")
```

Trying

```
open Odbc
```

fails with "Unbound module Odbc"

I'm building the code with

```
ocamlbuild -pkg odbc test.native
```

The generated documentation for the package seem to suggest I should be opening the "Ocamlodbc" module, but that also results in an "Unbound module" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

```
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkg odbc test.native
```

### Description

`-use-ocamlfind` tells `ocamlbuild` to use `ocamlfind` system to find libraries on your system.  Otherwise, without this flag, you need to provide flags with concrete locations and also take care of the package dependencies. So, it is a good idea to always use `ocamlfind`.

If this command still doesn't work for you, then make sure, that you chose the right package name. You can use `ocamlfind list` to look at the set of all packages available on your system.

### Further reading

While the above is ok for small programs, I would suggest to use `OASIS` system to handle all the flags for you.

You can start from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26207629/2625442) example, adapting dependency list to your neeeds.